# Qt Creator Failed to find/parse header files

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I started getting a strange issue lately. Qt Creator is not able to find or parse even standard header files. Please find below the screenshot of it, as you can see, the editor does not know what on earth is `qint32`.

There is no problem in compile, build or what ever in terms of build/debug functionality, its the Qt Editor annotations that got freaked out.

[image]

Any idea how can I reset the Qt Creator back to its normal world?

Comment: Do you mean `Qt Creator` instead of `Qt Editor`?

Comment: yup, Qt Creator.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, after updating Qt Creator.

In my case I couldn't even compile, build or run the application.
What worked for me was **switching off the Clang-Code-Model**.

Just go to Help->About Plugins....

Afterwards you have to restart Qt Creator.